# X11/Xlibint.h naming conflict issues: are they supposed to be named min/max?

Tags: c++, x11

In attempting to compile the SFML source code, I found an issue where std::min was suspiciously not recognised by the compiler, which gave the error of

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

Despite  being declared. Doing a manual trace I whittled the culprit file down to X11/Xlibint.h. Checking further I found these two hidden nasties declared:

```
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

Now I was always taught macros should either make use of starting underscores, all caps lock or a unique identifier to avoid precisely what has occurred here: a naming conflict. What I'm even more baffled by is why X11/Xlibint.h would make use of perhaps the absolutely most common terms min and max, especially in full knowledge that std::min and std::max, especially with using namespace std, become both min and max.

You can replicate the error in two ways, and depends on the order the header files are declared in. If X11/Xlibint.h is declared **after** algorithm, it overwrites the min/max definition, which you can see with the example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> //declares std::min std::max
#include <X11/Xlibint.h> //declares min / max macro, which seems to overwrite std:min / std::max

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Min is: "<<min(0,10)<<std::endl; //doesn't error
    std::cout<<"Min is: "<<std::min(0,10)<<std::endl; //errors with unqualified id despite algorithm being declared
}
```

Which produces the errors:

```
main.cpp|8|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token|
```

For those of you who would simply suggest in such a simple project to declare the headers the other way around, it's not possible in large projects or libraries to 100% ensure the order is the right way around (I had to trace through 30+ files in SFML just to find the source of the conflict), especially if a number of files declare algorithm because the clobber occurs when algorithm is declared before X11/libint.h (and given algorithm is more commonly used than X11/libint.h it's more likely to occur in that order).

It can also occur the other way around, but it's more convoluted:

```
#include <X11/Xlibint.h>

//Only defined if X11 already defines it. We redefine it to demonstrate it's used instead of std::min
#ifdef min
#undef min
#define min(a,b) -10;
#endif

int N = min(0,10); //Defined as a macro, implicitly

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int I = min(0,20); //No longer the macro, implicitly
    std::cout<<"N is: "<<N<<" I is: "<<I<<std::endl; //N is -10, I is 0
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot be the only one thinking that the declaration in X11/Xlibint.h of min/max was a poor choice of naming convention?

My proposal for fixing it would be to either:

1. Rename the macros (for example _MIN or _MAX), and/or
2. Undefining them prior to the header leaving scope.

Comment: X11 is a dinosaur. `min` and `max` is the least of its problems. Just `#undef` them wherever needed.

Comment: So, what is your question? This seems more asking for opinions than an actual question. You have to remember that X11 was developed long ago, long before the rise of C++. Are these macros badly names? Yes. Should we fix it? Sure, but it will take 20 years before the final version of that header file has disappeared from most distributions. Can we work around them? No problem...

Comment: I was not aware of the details of X11. I had presumed it was a set of maintained system files which could have been patched (but I did not know where or how I would go about reporting that). I was not aware of such pitfalls so I'm curious if there was perhaps some way to find out if there are any others (no comments or documentation?). Seeing as it cannot be patched, I suppose the question becomes 'what are the workarounds?' but I'm assuming it's #undef

Comment: @c1646091 They may be maintained, but "not breaking existing stuff" is (probably) high on the maintenance side. One could ask why C++ chose to define `std::min` and `std::max` when it is well-known that X11 have been using these since (most probably) the mid-80s, as well as complaining that X11 made a choice then, that now breaks for a language that this X11 header wasn't really designed to work with.